How is energy converted when matter is deformed?
This question pertains to a project we are doing in class. In the project, we are discussing the various forces governing certain sports. I chose basketball, and one of the main things to write about is the forces when a ball is being dribbled. Online, it stated that when a ball hits the ground, it is deformed and gains elastic potential energy. When it bounces up, this energy transforms to kinetic energy. I'm having trouble picturing this, however. How exactly does this process work? Also, is any kinetic energy lost in this process alone (disregarding sound and heat)? Finally, is this the only reason that balls bounce, or does Newton's third law play a part? Thanks for the help! Edit: I realize some of my info may be incorrect, but please clarify.


Online, it stated that when a ball hits the ground, it is deformed and gains elastic potential energy. When it bounces up, this energy transforms to kinetic energy. I'm having trouble picturing this, however. How exactly does this process work?

Transfers from kinetic energy to potential energy are handled by the Work-Energy theorm.
The transformation of kinetic energy to elastic potential energy is done via work. In this example, the initial kinetic energy is used for the work required to deform the object: A net force moves a point on the circumference a distance d.
Since the ball is elastic this work is stored as elastic potential energy. Once the ball rebounds, the elastic potential energy is used for the work required to restore the ball to its original shape and provide the final kinetic energy after rebound.

If you had a block with a spring beneath it, and dropped it onto the ground, the spring touches the ground first and the moving mass will compress it until the spring has absorbed all of the kinetic energy of the mass. The compressed spring then has elastic potential energy. But then the spring is compressed away from its equilibrium length, and it will decompress pushing the block back up into the air. That's basically how it works for all objects bouncing off the floor, the only difference is instead of an actual spring the material of the object itself is the spring- really a whole bunch of masses (atoms, molecules) connected by a whole bunch of springs (intermolecular bonds). Kinetic energy is definitely lost in this process, but quite literally as the sound (which turns into heat...) and heat that you wish to disregard. There will also be vibrations induced in the material of the ball and the floor which will gradually turn into...heat. If the material of the object permanently deforms (like clay will as opposed to rubber) then you can also lose energy to these "plastic" or permanent deformations. But guess what- the energy lost in a plastic deformation is lost as... heat!

Thanks! This is a good example. How exactly does sound energy become heat, though?

@user386598 Heat is just randomly distributed kinetic energy.  In the case of sound, air is not a mathematically perfect ideal medium for sound to travel in.  It's good, but not perfect.  There's a little bit of dispersion as the random banging together of air atoms doesn't quite match the ideal equations for sound transmission.  Given that these random events happen quite literally in the trillions per second (or even higher), we end up losing track of the energy dispersed, and instead we model it as random motion of air particles.  The kinetic energy of those random motions is heat.

I don't agree with the description of sound: the main process here is not dissipation, but a power flux through sound that is produced by compression/expansionof the ball during the bounce, and it's carried away by the sound (perturbation) produced, and transferred into the neighboring environment

@basics, what part specifically are you disagreeing with? That kinetic energy of the ball is lost to the generation of sound? That sound will eventually dissipate into heat?

eventually eventually. Sound is nearly a conservative process. Sound is taking energy away from the "system ball" since it transfers energy to the external environment. Then, it could be dissipated in air or with the interaction of other bodies. However, if we're interested in the "system ball", once it's transferred by the "system ball" to the environement, we don't really care where this perturbation goes, as soon as the environment doesn't transfer (with a kind of feedback) energy to the ball through sound

@basics OK- none of what you are saying sounds inconsistent with anything I said. The ball loses energy to the production of sound, which flows away from the ball.  "We don't really care about where this perturbation goes"- I sure might if I live below you, and you are bouncing a heavy ball on your floor/ my ceiling!

As the ball compresses slightly when it hits the ground, it resists this compression, because it puts the ball in tension. Things in general don't "want" to be in tension, because it increases the potential energy of the system - something that thermodynamics says all physical systems resist. Because energy had to go into putting the ball in tension, that energy doesn't disappear, but rather becomes "elastic potential energy" (EPE).
Think of it like this: you take a basketball in your hands and try and squish it. It doesn't squish, unless it's either a very low-quality basketball or very deflated. But of course you're spending energy to try and squish it, and that energy goes into the "elastic potential energy" of the basketball. The more EPE it has, the more deformed it is.
In order to "un-deform" after hitting the floor and deforming, the ball will then start releasing its EPE, and insodoing increases its kinetic energy, because that EPE can't just disappear. Then, the ball bounces back up, having kinetic energy once again!

Thank you, this clears up a lot! However, I have one question: Does the EPE transform into kinetic energy before bouncing up, or after?

@user386598 It is transformed not before nor after, but during the bouncing process.  The act of "bouncing" is defined by the transformation of energy.


Online, it stated that when a ball hits the ground, it is deformed and
gains elastic potential energy.

When the ball hits the ground the kinetic energy it had just prior to the collision is totally converted to elastic potential energy stored in the ball only if the collision is perfectly elastic. But no real collision at the macroscopic level is perfectly elastic. So some energy will be dissipated in the form of heat and sound, as well as energy lost if there is  any permanently deformation of the ball.

When it bounces up, this energy transforms to kinetic energy.

That's true only if the collision is perfectly elastic. Otherwise, when the ball decompresses is loses some energy so that its kinetic energy coming off the ground is less than the elastic potential energy it when it came to a stop after impact.

How exactly does this process work? Also, is any kinetic energy lost
in this process alone (disregarding sound and heat)?

Disregarding sound and heat, kinetic energy would only be lost if there were  some permanent (no recoverable) deformation of the ball.

Finally, is this the only reason that balls bounce, or does Newton's
third law play a part?

Newton's third law is related to conservation of momentum. The momentum of the Earth-ball system is conserved regardless of whether or not the collision is elastic.
Hope this helps.
